# Calculate total and elapsed number of working days in the month for a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am stuck with a SQL query.

I am trying to calculate two different things in a same query:

1. Number of business days in a month (this will exclude weekends).
2. How many days working days have been passed in a month.

Let's say for November (as on 11/9/2018)

```
no.of business days        no. of business days passed
22                                7
```

I tried like this :

```
WITH cteAllDates AS 
(
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

    SET @StartDate = '10/01/2018'
    SET @EndDate = '10/31/2018'

    SELECT
        (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
        - (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS x
) AS y
SELECT x
FROM cteAllDates
```

I would like to create  a virtual table so that I can use these fields in my complete query. And if its possible I can do this with `GETDATE()` and not to declare dates every time.

Comment: should  `no.of business days ` be 22 in NOV?

Comment: I would recommend creating a calendar table with lots of precalculated data, e.g. number of business days in a month. In your case you can add a *business day number" starting with the first day of your calendar which increases only for business days (it's easy to exclude public holidays, too). Now the number of business days between two dates is calculated as a difference using two joins to the calendar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to do it in a CTE, and based on the earlier answer you found on SO, here is a version that does it all for the current month without needing to define start and end dates:

EDIT: To create a holiday table

First, create a holiday table. Don't do this every time, make it a persistent table, and keep it filled up with all holidays you need - easter, xmas etc.

```
create table holidays(holiday date)
insert holidays values ('2018-09-23'),('2018-09-24')
```

Now the query, including the check for number of holidays between the dates

```
;with dates as(
    select dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())) as startofmonth,
    dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(d,-day(getdate())+1,convert(date,getdate())))) as endofmonth,
    convert(date,getdate()) as today
)
,holidaycount as (
    select count(*) as holidaysinmonth,
        sum(case when holiday<=today then 1 else 0 end) as holidaystodate
    from dates
    join holidays on holiday between startofmonth and endofmonth
)
,daycounts as(
    select dates.*,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, endofmonth) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, endofmonth) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, endofmonth) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaysinmonth,0) as wkdaysinmonth,

       (DATEDIFF(dd, startofmonth, today) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, startofmonth, today) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startofmonth) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, today) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -isnull(holidaystodate,0) as wkdaystodate

    from dates
    cross join holidaycount
) 

select * from daycounts
```

EDIT: If you cant create a temp table, add this as an additional CTE before the holidaycount one like so:

```
,holidays as (
    select holiday from (values ('2018-11-23'),('2018-11-24')) t(holiday)
)
,holidaycount as (
```

Comment: @TomC..Thanku for replying me out..this is really working out good. But I would like to know if in November I would like to exclude 23 and 24 november from this ( i mean those are holidays). how i will add that to this query?

Comment: Once you start adding in holidays then you go towards the other suggestions in the comments and other answers - where you create a separate calendar table that includes every date, and flags for working days, holidays etc. Then it becomes a simple case of counting the relevant days.

Comment: @TomC..can u please show me how to do it?..In november i want to exclude 22nd november..How i will create a calender table?

Comment: I have updated to use a simple holiday table that just contains the holiday dates. Make sure you only enter week day holidays.

Comment: @TomC..Hi I am getting an error There is already an object named 'holidays' in the database.

Comment: As I explained in the answer, you only ever do that part once, not every time you run the query. Create the table, and keep it up to date with all holidays going forward. If there was already a table called holidays *before* you started this then call it something else.

Comment: ..I understand what u meant but in my database i cannot create a table..So i need to store this create table thing virtually or if possible create a table with CTE.and then use it in this query

Comment: Well its easy enough to use a temp table or add it as a CTE, but that defeats the idea of making it work for any month. You would have to update the query to keep adding holidays. Is that ok for you?

Comment: Hi Tom..yes it worked with temp table but i have to do it manually then, as create table is not working or if there is some other way out

Comment: I have added an extra CTE - see bottom of my answer. This will do it without any table creation but you will have to update this each time you have a new holiday, for example xmas, easter, etc.

Comment: @TomC..Thanku so much

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use cte recursive make a calendar table, then use condition aggregate function to get your result.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1));
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()));

;WITH CTE AS (
    select @StartDate startdt,@EndDate enddt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD (day ,1 , startdt) , @EndDate
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD (day,1,startdt) <= @EndDate
)


select SUM(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startdt) NOT IN ('Sunday','Saturday') THEN 1 END) 'no.of business days',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, startdt) NOT IN ('Sunday','Saturday') AND GETDATE() >= startdt THEN 1 END) 'no. of business days passed'
FROM CTE
```

[sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/IDF32455)

**Result**

```
no.of business days     no. of business days passed
22                      7
```

Comment: @D-Shih..This query is not returning me any results.

Comment: @jsingh sqlfiddle work good... maybe you can check the `@StartDate ` and `@EndDate`  var